# how to avoid the error message java.lang.ClassCastException spark sql 2.3.1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have some code lines that execute preprocessing from dataset:

```
val clean_data = resultDf.na.replace("verkehrsstatus", Map("aktuell nicht ermittelbar" -> "normales Verkehrsaufkommen"))

val datawithudf = clean_data.withColumn("state", udfState()($"verkehrsstatus"))
val finaldata = datawithudf.select($"auswertezeit", $"strecke_id", $"state", $"geschwindigkeit", $"coordinates").withColumnRenamed("state", "verkehrsstatus")
finaldata.printSchema()
finaldata.take(2).foreach(println)
```

When I want to  display a few sample records from the final DataFrame, I receive this message error:

> WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, 192.168.56.102, executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1417)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2293)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)